# trying to insert integer into byte array

Tags: go

I have an array of bytes

```
app0 := []byte("\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

I am trying to figure out how to replace `app0[13:15]` with two bytes containing `300`.

Please help. I tried the following but it won't even compile:

```
app0[13:15] = []byte(300)
```

Comment: yes, 300 fits into two bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused what you are even trying to do with

```
app0[13:15] = []byte(300)
```

A single byte can't hold the value 300, and you have a slice of bytes.  I'll assume you want the value 300 converted into two bytes:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    app0 := []byte("\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
    app0 =  append(app0[:13], append(intToBytes(uint16(300)), app0[15:]...)...)
    fmt.Println(app0)
}

func intToBytes(i uint16) []byte {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, i)
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qADHwCCFQG

The trick here is you have to actually get an array of bytes, and then you can use the variadic operator (`...`) and then `append` function to replace the inner elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    app0 := []byte("\xff\xe0\x00\x10\x4a\x46\x49\x46\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
    fmt.Println(app0)
    app0[13], app0[14] = 300>>8, 300&0xFF
    fmt.Println(app0)
}
```

Output:

```
[255 224 0 16 74 70 73 70 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[255 224 0 16 74 70 73 70 0 1 1 1 0 1 44 0 0 0]
```

Comment: thank you very much. this code is not portable. it will work correctly only on little-endian architecture, am I right?

Comment: @akonsu: For little-endian architecture, write: `app0[13], app0[14] = 300&0xFF, 300>>8`.